# FCM, no puedo crear temas/topicos para enviar notificaciones

Tags: android, firebase

tengo una aplicación que utiliza el servicio de notificaciones de firebase, el problema, es que no puedo crear temas o topicos, viendo la documentacion se crearia con la siguiente linea:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(nuevasVias);
```

les dejare las 2 clases que utilizo y el manifiesto:

```
public class Firebase_Instance_ID_Service extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    final static String tokenPreferenceKey="fcm_token";
    final static String nuevasVias="Nuevas Ciclovias";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh(){
        super.onTokenRefresh();
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        sharedPreferences.edit().putString(tokenPreferenceKey, FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());


        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(nuevasVias);
    }
}
```

la segunda clase es:

```
public class NotificacionesFirebase extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage){

        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(Firebase_Instance_ID_Service.nuevasVias);
        if(remoteMessage.getFrom().equals("/topics/"+Firebase_Instance_ID_Service.nuevasVias)){
            recibirMensaje("Nuevas Ciclovías",remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
        else{
                recibirMensaje("CicloMapp",remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

    }

    private void recibirMensaje(String title,String contentText){
        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Intent intent= new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder= new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(contentText);
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationBuilder.setSound(defaultSoundUri);
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo);
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

y el manifiesto

```
<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<application
    android:name=".Facebook"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="value" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Inicio"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".Inicio" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Registrarse" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".Valoraraciones" />
    <activity android:name=".Reportar" />
    <activity android:name=".agregarRuta" />
    <activity android:name=".Tiendas"></activity>
    <service android:name=".NotificacionesFirebase">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".Firebase_Instance_ID_Service">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

pd: solo tengo problemas con la creacion de topicos, puedo enviar notificaciones a todos los usuarios o a uno en especifico, el problema, es que no se crea el tema

Comment: Buenas tardes Zhet, Cómo estas? Che te hago una consulta... yo estoy en un caso que vos pudiste resolver, pero yo no encuentro la manera de hacerlo... ¿Cómo hiciste para mandar notificaciones a TODOS LOS USUARIOS?. En el Post de HTTP, no pones "to"?. Me darías un ejemplo del post qué haces o de dónde sacaste la info? Desde ya muchas gracias! Saludos, Fabrizio

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59082/discussion-on-question-by-zhet-fcm-no-puedo-crear-temas-topicos-para-enviar-not).

Comment: @Fabrizio Cuando tengas 20 puntos de reputación, podrás hablar en el chat. Mientras tanto, debes preguntar o responder otras publicaciones, pero correctamente.

Comment: Siguen sin aparecer los temas?